# How does objects context and scope got accessed?

Tags: javascript

I have a code snippet like this:

```
/** @constructor */
Person = function() {
    // member method
    this.say = function() {
        return "I'm an instance.";
    }

    // inner function
    function say() {
        return "I'm inner.";
    }
}
// static method
Person.say = function() {
    return "I'm static.";
}

var p = new Person();
p.say();      //=> I'm an instance.
Person.say(); //=> I'm static.
// there is no way to directly access the inner function from here
```

I learned that

```
function say() { ... }
```

is just identical to

```
var say;
say = function() { ... }
```

which is identical to

```
var say;
this.say = function() { ... }
```

So why the **inner function** did not override the **member method**?

**-----EDIT-----**
I am still confused, is `this` the object that holds all local variables? Let's take some more examples here.

```
// Tested both in node.js and Chrome 34
var t = "stackoverflow";
console.log(t); //=> stackoverflow
console.log(this.t); //=> stackoverflow
```

So this means, when I declared a local variable, I can access it via the `this` keyword.

```
// Tested both in node.js and Chrome 34
this.t = "stackoverflow";
console.log(t); //=> stackoverflow
console.log(this.t); //=> stackoverflow
```

This means, when I assign an attribute to `this`, I can access it via the local scope. This is confusing! So is it just like there are two `wrappers` for the function, one is the context `this`, another is the scope?
So now the way I understand this mechanism is:

- Say I declared a variable in the scope, let's name it `tmp`. And then if I access it via `this`, the JSVM will first lookup `this` to see if `this.tmp` exists. If not, it will then look for `tmp`. If it is not found, then I get `undefined`.
- I declared a variable in `this`, let's name it `this.tmp`. And then if I access it by simply writing `tmp`, the JSVM will first lookup the scope to see if `tmp` exists. If not, it will then see if `this.tmp` exists. If it is not found, then I get `undefined`.

Am I right?

Comment: `say = function` isn't the same as `this.say = function`.

Comment: @Barmar Why? Isn't `say` defined in the current context `this`?

Comment: `function say(){...}` being identical to `var say = function(){...}` depends totally on variable scope. [read MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)

Comment: In the way you have declared it here, your inner function will probably get garbage collected soon after object construction.

Comment: Isn't `this` the object that holds local variables?

Comment: @JohnWu: Nope. Consider `function foo() {console.log(this); var bar = 42; } foo();`. I hope you know that `this` refers to the global object (`window`) in that case. According to your logic that means the *local* variable `bar` becomes a property of the global object, and thus becomes a *global* variable. How weird would that be?! If you want to learn more about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake when you say that

```
var say;
say = function () { ... }
```

is identical to

```
var say;
this.say = function () { ... }
```

and to understand why you need to understand the `this` keyword. This keyword holds a reference to the object to which the function using it belongs. When inside a constructor you want to reference the object being constructed and so you use `this`. In that case, when you put something into `this` you are putting this into the object that the constructor will generate.

In that sense, the second block of code will provide you with an object with one property `say` that happens to be a function.

When you use constructors in javascript, the only things that will be exposed by the object are those that you attribute to it using the `this` keyword. On the other hand, an internal function is a function that is in the scope of your constructor and can be used there, but is not exposed because you didn't want so.

Compare it to this function that happens to build an object literal:

```
function buildMyObject() {

    function doSomething (obj) { ... }

    var objToBuild = { };

    doSomething(objToBuild);

    return objToBuild;
}
```

In that case, probably by convenience, you define a function to do something on your object and use it inside this function that builds your object. The object is returned, but see that the function that done work on it is hidden because it is just in the scope of `buildMyObject`. This is analogous to your situation with functions inside constructors: they provide utilities you might find useful inside the constructor, but they are hidden from the outer world because of scope.

**EDIT:** The `this` keyword can be briefly described as follows: when you use it inside a function, `this` holds a reference to the object to which the function belongs. In other words, the `this` function holds a reference to the current instance, being that the one which holds the function.

Now your first example

```
// Tested both in node.js and Chrome 34
this.t = "stackoverflow";
console.log(t); //=> stackoverflow
console.log(this.t); //=> stackoverflow
```

Why this happens? Well, because in that case, the object to which the function belongs is simply `window`. In that case, both `t` and `this.t` are the same because `this` holds a reference to the `window` object.

Although you must be aware of scope when using `this` because it is scope dependent, this keyword simply holds this reference to the object possesing the function on which it is used.

Comment: `this` keyword is mainly used as a reference to the current instance which includes the constructor function; other than that, +1 :)

Comment: So `this` has nothing to do with local variable in the scope? That is weird! I've always think that `this` is the object that holds local variables.

Comment: @JohnWu: *"So `this` has nothing to do with local variable in the scope?"* Yes. Scope and `this` are two different animals.

Comment: @FelixKling I am still confused, I know the context (`this`) is not the scope, but I don't know how it works. I edited my question and add some more examples.

Comment: @JohnWu, I've added one edit about this. See if it helps a little more.

Comment: @user1620696 Very helpful, I just learned something new! Thanks and +1!

Answer (score 1):

`this.say` and `Person.say` assign to properties of the object. An inner function is a local variable in the scope of the function, not a property of the object.